# Kendo combobox always picks the first item

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

```
select: function (e: any) {
    var selectedItem = this.dataSource.data()[e.item.index()];
```

Is there an alternative way for doing this selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`dataItem()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#methods-dataItem):

```
var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/Oquxu)

Comment: I had tried that too..somehow still didn't work for me .. I will try it once again.. If didn't work then you think problem is somewhere else in the code?  ...

Comment: @KSNoob well, it is strange, i tell you. With kendo UI I always use `dataItem()` passing an element with `data-uid` attribute, it is how it should be used, and always works. E.g. it is like if you pass a `tr` to grid's `dataItem()`. It should work. If it doesn't works, I suggest you to add a live demo in dojo.telerik.com with your issue.

Comment: looks like it is working now :)  maybe my cache wasn't empty when I tried it yesterday... cools

Comment: @KSNoob great!!